# What is the difference between AsyncPostBack and SyncPostBack?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, postback

What is AsyncPostBack, SyncPostBack and what is the difference between those methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asynchronous postback is accomplished using javascript to send an XMLHttpRequest, known as [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), without leaving the web page you are on.  A synchronous postback is a normal form post request from the web page, resulting in a complete request cycle and a (re)display of the same or a different web page.  The difference is that with an asynchronous request the web page stays the same and the user can continue to interact with it while the request is taking place.  This can make the interface seem more responsive to the user and improve the experience.  In a synchronous, or full, postback the web browser must wait while the request is sent back and the new page is loaded.  You also lose, if you don't maintain it on the server and reset it on the new page, any state on the original web page.